# How can I transform MsBuild ItemGroup into a PropertyGroup?

Tags: msbuild, msbuild-4.0

I have an ItemGroup as:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <FilesToExclude Include="One.dll;Two.dll" />
</ItemGroup>
```

I want to be able to have a property group which has the concatenated result of the above dlls producing (excluding the double quotes):

```
"-x!One.dll -x!Two.dll"
```

I am currently using:

```
    <tmp>
      -x! @(FilesToExclude)
    </tmp>
```

which is producing:

```
"-x!One.dll;Two.dll"
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specify the delimiter for concatenation:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <FilesToExclude Include="One.dll;Two.dll"/>
</ItemGroup>

<PropertyGroup>
  <tmp>-x!@(FilesToExclude, ' -x!')</tmp>
</PropertyGroup>
```

To be confident of evaluation order in this sample move the PropertyGroup definition inside a Target.